# make anchor text link's in more than 100 posts in a specific period of time

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hyperlink

I need to write on a Wp database (inside the posts) an anchor text link for a given keyword in more than 100 posts in a specific period of time (posts published between 16-01-2013 and 23-05-2013).

I've considered the use of a plugin but apart from the date range not being possible, all the links must stay on the post once the plugin is disabled...

I also thought using a sql query but it will write the links on the images and O don't know how to set a time range on it

```
 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'my keyword', '<a href="#">my keyword</a>' );
```

Is there an easy way to do this or I have to do this by hand?

Comment: whats about WHERE... the publish date would be another field of wp_posts

Comment: that could be fine but the question is that it also writes links over the images titles and alt tags...

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it will write the links on the images"?

Comment: This is how the image code it would looks like after I run that sql query

`<img class="alignleft" title="<a href="#">my keyword</a>" src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/my-image.jpg" alt="<a href="#">my keyword</a>" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'my keyword', '<a href="#">my keyword</a>' ) WHERE <insert date field> >= 2013-01-16 AND <insert date field> <= '2013-05-23';
```

Comment: this sql will make my images code wrong like this: `<img class="alignleft" title="<a href="#">my keyword</a>" src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/my-image.jpg" alt="<a href="#">my keyword</a>" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post_date_gmt or the post_date field. The following example is using the gmt date

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'my keyword', '<a href="#">my keyword</a>' ) WHERE post_date_gmt >= '2013-01-16 00:00:00' and post_date_gmt <= '2013-05-23 23:59:59'
```

to prevent editing image titles is more complicated. I think i would do a foreach for all content-fields in timespace and use a regex for find out what to replace.

I found another post about that problem:
http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/php-regexp-replace-words-in-html-string-if-not-inside-tags/

Comment: the problem with the solution on the link is the performance. And that's one of the reasons why i need this to be written inside the post content itself. too bad for me...

Comment: sorry but i thought about writing an update-script which updates all post_content fields in your database. Not about replacing it every time a post is displayed. so you shouldnt have performance problems when running the update once.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to write an update script and to be honest I haven't thought on that when I read the post. but thanks, @steven

Answer (score 0):

OK, this isn't the way to go about this but whatever!

If you're worried about the links being destroyed then before you run the update keyword query just run a couple of other queries like

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'title="my keyword"', 'title="Xmy keywordX"'`

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'alt="my keyword"', 'alt="Xmy keywordX"'`

That way the links wont get screwed with.

Then run your update query

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'my keyword', '<a href="#">my keyword</a>' )`

Then set the title and alt back.

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'title="Xmy keywordX"', 'title="my keyword"'`

`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'alt="Xmy keywordX"', 'alt="my keyword"'`

As i said, not the best way to go about it.

I'd query for the all the records then loop through them and regex replace the stuff i wanted in a similar fashion to the link that Steven posted.

Comment: problem wit that (cleaver idea and it will be useful to others...) is other words around the alt and title. For instance, if you only have **my keyword** in those fields, this works just fine. **But** if you have any other words together like **my keyword is nice** this method won't work.

Comment: Do the keywords you want to change always appear after the images?

Comment: yes, they do! but in some cases they are not right after the image closing tag.  In that case, is there any other way to work around the above method?